# AWS Pinpoint - Both 'Campaign' and 'Test messaging' fail to send email

Tags: aws-pinpoint

I followed the following guide to setup an AWS Pinpoint project:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/gettingstarted-create-campaign.html

After I launch the campaign, the email is not sent (I chose 'immediately'). So, I checked 'Test messaging'. It also failed to send mail. I had already activated my sender email address.

The campaign analytics says:

Messages sent - 1
Messages delivered - 1
Delivery rate - 100%
Email open rate - 0%
Bounce rate - 0%

May I know why the mails are not delivered by AWS Pinpoint please?

Answer (score 1):

**This is my be due to Sandbox mode having following restrictions:**

Limitations Of Sandbox Mode :-

- You can send an email only from verified addresses and domains
- addresses that are associated with the mailbox simulator. maximum of
- 200 messages per 24-hour and  maximum of one message per second.